# Pass values by reference in perl

Tags: perl

I want to pass two values to a function: The name of the hash and the file location.

I have 2 variables `$file_location_1` and `$file_location_2`. The function is used to create a hash.

My question is: Can I pass the name of the hash and the 2 variables in the function?

```
enter code here
sub compare
{
   open(INFILE,$file)
   while<INFILE>
   {
     %hash{xyz}=pqr;
    }
 }
   compare(\%abc,file_location_1);
   compare(\%uvw,file_location_2);
```

Comment: I wish I could understand what you are asking

Comment: Again, I don't know what you want... so I couldn't even help to say if it's right or wrong.  Your subroutine should assign parameters though, see my answer

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but you should use the 3-argument form of the `open` function: `open my $INFILE, '<', $file;`.  See `perldoc -f open`

Comment: -1 for posting code with syntax errors (where the question was not about the syntax errors)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
sub compare
{
   my ($hr,$file) = @_;

   open(INFILE,$file);
   while<INFILE>
   {
      $hr->{xyz}=pqr;
   }
   close INFILE;
}

compare(\%abc,$file_location_1);
compare(\%uvw,$file_location_2);
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense.. why would you want to assign a value to a hashref as many times as you have lines in the code?

Comment: I'm taking the `xyz` and `pqr` to be pseudo-code for some other process (perhaps inside a conditional regex), but Zaid is right, if that is the literal code, then you need to re-evaluate what you want.

Comment: well because i am using the file i have two make a hash and then using it to compare two files.I have to build a unique key and then compare.

Comment: it depends on how you're trying to compare... you can create two file handles and compare them word by word if you want.  It all depends on what you're trying to do

Comment: well yes..but then i have already process the   my ($hr,$file) = @_;  part and stored it in a variable called file)location_1 and file_location_2. So i do not want to do this in the subroutinr.

Comment: well thanks now i understood that the parameters need to be shifted from @_ in order to assign them to the variable.Thanks @ vol7ron.

Comment: @kunal: yes, otherwise you would need to use global variables, which is not recommended (poor programming practice).  have fun and good luck